# OAI-PHM. do not update record

Tags: dspace, oai, oai-pmh

I have a problem with the DSPACE and the OAI-PHM, it is not possible to update the records in the OAI `../oai/request?verb=ListSets`, It shows me the old configuration and old records (33) Now they are 97. As I show you the output of the command:

```
curl http://localhost:8080/solr/oai/select?q=*:*&indent=true&rows=0
```

Return
numFound="97"

because the OAI-PMH on the client's side is not updated with 97 records.

A help please,
Thanks

Comment: You might want to provide more details (perhaps a [mcve]) and describe clearly what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: Sure, I describe what I run on the console:
[root @ Centos7A10 bin] # ./dspace oai clean-cache
OAI 2.0 manager action started
Purging cached OAI responses.
OAI 2.0 manager action ended. It took 0 seconds.
[root @ Centos7A10 bin] # ./dspace oai import -c
OAI 2.0 manager action started
Clearing index
Index cleared
Using full import
Full import
Total: 97 items
OAI 2.0 manager action ended. It took 6 seconds.
[root @ Centos7A10 bin] #
But on the client side it only shows 33 records (http://repositorio.uct.edu.pe/oai/request?verb=ListSets)

Comment: Why not [edit] your question so that all the detail is in the same place. Comments can get deleted.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have run the correct DSpace commands but possibly in the wrong order.

- dspace oai import - this will find new records and add them to the index
- dspace oai import -c - this will rebuild the entire index
- dspace oai clean-cache will recreate the cache from the newly updated index.

I recommend running dspace oai clean-cache again.

Comment: Thanks @terrywb, one last query to close the topic, the links of the OAI (Identify|Sets|Records|Identifiers| Metadata Formats) are shown with the path localhost:8080, although I already modified the file oai.cfg and put repositorio.uct.edu.pe, Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: After modifying the oai.cfg file, be certain to run mvn, run ant, restart tomcat, and then run oai clean-cache.  If these steps do not resolve your issue, post a new question here or check one of the other support channels for DSpace.